# How can I subscribe to Bloomberg API?

Tags: blpapi

I know it's kind of redundant questions what I previously asked. [How can I start Bloomberg API in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921529/how-can-i-start-bloomberg-api-in-python). But I cannot really figure out how to subscribe in this by python. When I run the code to run another module "finmarketpy",

```
options = blpapi.SessionOptions()
options.setServerHost('TCAA20171038')
options.setServerPort('Don't know')
session = blpapi.Session(options)
session.start()
```

it gets error code like, `in method 'blpapi_SessionOptions_setServerPort', argument 2 of type 'unsigned short'` Getting Bloomberg became essential bringing other type of module. So please be generous and teach me.

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done without installation to Bloomgberg